# Java MYSQL error No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, database-connection

I am really stuck with this problem so I would be glad is someone could help me out!

I made a login page in java and created a MYSQL connection inside. The code works fine if you try to login the first time but after you logout and try to login again I get this error:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

```
This is my code:
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static Connection conn = connectionDb.getInstance().getConnection();

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get username and pass from the html page.
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("userpass");

        // put the username and variables in the getset.
        getset sets = new getset();
        sets.setUserName(userName);
        sets.setPassword(password);

        // send the data to the database 
        try {
            DbManager.Read(sets);
            // if the userinfo is correct following actions will perform:
            if (DbManager.authentication == true) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", "");
                // setting session to expiry in 30 mins
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30 * 60);
                Cookie username = new Cookie("user", userName);
                response.addCookie(username);
                response.sendRedirect("MyAccount.jsp");
                DbManager.authentication = false;
                // if the userinfo wasn't correct the following actions will perform:
            } else if (DbManager.authentication == false) {
                out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request
                        .getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }
            // catches erros.
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                connectionDb.getInstance().close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and DBManager

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class DbManager {

    public static Connection conn = connectionDb.getInstance().getConnection();
    public static boolean authentication;
    public static ResultSet rs;
    public static PreparedStatement pstmt, pstmt1, pstmt2;

    public static void Insert(getset set) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        try {

            // insert username and password
            String sql = "INSERT INTO logininfo(username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, set.getUserName());
            pstmt.setString(2, set.getPassword());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            // insert user info
            String sql1 = "INSERT INTO userinfo(fullName, email, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber, companyName, companyEmail, paymentMethod) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pstmt1.setString(1, set.getFullName());
            pstmt1.setString(2, set.getEmail());
            pstmt1.setString(3, set.getDateOfBirth());
            pstmt1.setString(4, set.getPhoneNumber());
            pstmt1.setString(5, set.getCompanyName());
            pstmt1.setString(6, set.getCompanyEmail());
            pstmt1.setString(7, set.getPaymentMethod());
            pstmt1.executeUpdate();
            connectionDb.getInstance().close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Read(getset set) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM logininfo where username='"+ set.getUserName() +"' and password='"+ set.getPassword() +"';";
            pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.println(set.getUserName());
            rs = pstmt2.executeQuery(sql);

            if (rs.next()) {
                authentication = true;
                connectionDb.getInstance().close();
            } else {
                authentication = false;
                connectionDb.getInstance().close();
            }
            pstmt2.close();
            rs.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (pstmt2 != null)
                    pstmt2.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

and connectionDb
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class connectionDb {

    private static connectionDb instance = null;

    private final String USERNAME = "root";
    private final String PASSWORD = "!i1w2g3w#";
    private final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";

    private Connection conn = null;

    private connectionDb() {
    }

    public static connectionDb getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new connectionDb();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private boolean openConnection() {
        try {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn == null) {
            if (openConnection()) {
                System.out.println("Connection Opened");
                return conn;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
        //return conn;
    //}
    public void close(){
        System.out.println("Close connection");
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn=null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Paste Full readable stack trace formatted. Also relevant code where you get the exception.

Comment: See all those statics in your code? They all need to go. When you manage to learn enough proper Java programming and code design that you can do it without creating a static hell, you'll find that your current problems disappear as if by magic.

Comment: If we remove the statics it only shows more errors.

Comment: I removed some errors but now I have this left: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getInstance() from the type connectionDb
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field DbManager.authentication
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field DbManager.authentication
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field DbManager.authentication

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with class level instantiation of connection object,instantiate within the method that will resolve the problem.Also there should not be connection getting close in servlet,remove instantiation and closing of connection from servlet as this code should be in db manager.

Comment: Could you please explain with an example how we could do this?

Comment: Yes sure...please list down the steps like login,save in db like that then  can help you out.

Comment: You mean the steps how we login? 1. We go to login.jsp 2. We put our login info and press login button 3. then login servlets starts and creates a connection to the database to check the userinfo 4. then the connection closes 5. till here everything works fine. 6. However if you redo the process we got an error 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: I will provide you the steps                                                                  1- Create two methods in in login manager class validateUser and second is loginsuer.These methods will take connection object from db manager class and make sure to close the connection in same method.this will resolve the issue